# Cake php 3 insert column in a table from a controller

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Good day! Making a website on Cakephp 3. Got a question. How can I insert column in a table from a controller? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, of course, but either not found or not understood. I need when I come data method post in controller create a column in a table based on the coming data. If not difficult prompt where to look then

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

Comment: To be clear, do you want to save the submitted data as a new row in the table, or do you want to create a brand new column (i.e. change the schema of the table)? If the former, it should all be very clearly covered in the tutorial that you did; this is the standard "add" function.

Comment: with saving the data no problem. I need to change the table structure. Create a new column. For example, using POST it $this->request->data('new_column_name'). I need to create in my table 'My_tabel' new column 'new_column_name'

Answer (score 1):

You can write raw SQL using an instance of your [connection](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html).

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

// In your controller
$sql = "ALTER table `schema`.`table` ADD COLUMN `field` VARCHAR(45);";
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$connection->execute($sql);
```

> I'm not sure why you would want to do this, you may want to reconsider your reasoning.

There is also the [schema system](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html) which provides useful methods for reading/dropping/creating schemes -you would lose all of the data in that table though (or need to create a really slow method that stores all the data in memory and adds it back after dropping/creating).

Answer (score -1):

```
Finish this tutorial please before start with cake 3
```

[Cake 3 tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html)